# how to set correct margin for nexus5 and nexus 5x

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing the app and now I have very big problem.

As we know nexus 5 and nexus 5x using the same resource directory (xxhdpi) my view getting broken because of some margins.

i.e I have to put 40dp for nexus 5 and 65dp for nexus5x.

So what should do here to make it works in 2 devices? 
Is there a way to set layout dimensions correct for both devices.

[image]

Comment: Density pixels (dp) scale to the density of the device. If you are seeing different results, then both devices don't have the same screen density

Comment: @cricket_007 see the edited question. Yeah they are different. But both device using the same resource directory. what should do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use **Android Percent Support Lib** which **divide your layout View into Percentage**....

It is easy to **set Views using Percentage** which is **useful for all device** and **UI is same** in all device .....

Use below link ....

[Android Percent Support Lib](https://github.com/JulienGenoud/android-percent-support-lib-sample)

I think it solve you problem ....

enjoy coding ....