# How to change width ImageView to correct ratio?

Tags: android, imageview

I have this XML file with a RelativeLayout. In this RelativeLayout I have got an ImageView and a LinearLayout with a lot of Views (not displayed in the code).

```
   <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:id="@+id/imageViewDemo"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageViewDemo"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageViewDemo"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageViewDemo"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageViewDemo"
            android:gravity="center"

            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!-- A lot of stuff -->

        </LinearLayout>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

I want the ImageView have the same width/height ratio as the ratio of the phone/tablet screen size. The height should just match the parent view, but the width must be changed to match the correct ratio. The LinearLayout must be inside the ImageView. I can simply not find a working solution.

Comment: use this concept your problem will be solve http://stackoverflow.com/a/38864774/5305430

Comment: have you tried android:scaleType="fitCenter"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the `ImageView` have the same width/height ratio as the ratio of the phone/tablet screen size.

First you should get the phone/tablet screen size in order to compute the width/height ratio.

This code get the ratio:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
int width = metrics.widthPixels;
int height = metrics.heightPixels;
final float screenRatio = ((float)width/(float)height);
```

> The height should just match the parent view, but the width must be changed to match the correct ratio.

For this purpose, you should change the `ImageView`'s width in code, the height should be specified `match_parent` in your layout.

This code can help you change the width :

```
imageView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        imageView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

        int height = imageView.getHeight();
        int resultWidth = (int)(height * screenRatio);

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = imageView.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.width = resultWidth;
        imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }
});
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks! I had to change one small thing though; 'float screenRatio = (float)(width/height);' returns 0. I changed it to 'final float screenRatio =((float)width/(float)height);'

Comment: I'm sorry made such a mistake, I will modify my answer. It's very happy to help you.  : )