# Layout resizing issue for different screens

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to resize my app's layout according to the screen sizes available but could not achieve the same. I made two layouts for landscape and portrait mode, but its contents(edit texts) which are included inside a linear layout are not getting resized according to the screens.

Here are my layouts:

**Activity_Login(portrait):**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.prosares.intralive.LoginActivity2">


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lin_all"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center">



<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/login"

    />


</LinearLayout>



<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lin_all1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
   >

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:hint="Username"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:background="@drawable/eventpopuprect"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/username"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text=""
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/eventpopuprect"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/password"
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText"
    android:hint="password"
    android:text=""
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButtonLogin"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/login_button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Activity_Login(landscape):**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context="com.prosares.intralive.LoginActivity2"
android:orientation="vertical">


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lin_all"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/login"

    />
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lin_all1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:hint="Username"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:background="@drawable/eventpopuprect"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/username"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:text=""
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/eventpopuprect"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/password"
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText"
    android:hint="password"
    android:text=""
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButtonLogin"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/login_button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_gravity="right" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you problem is same as this problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/38864774/5305430

Comment: check [different screen size](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37207973/2826147)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have set width and height as wrap_content. Go for giving the static height with with the help of different values folders for different screen sizes. In different files you have to give same dimen name with different values.

```
res/values/dimens.xml(default)
res/values-ldpi/dimens.xml   (240x320 and nearer resolution)
res/values-mdpi/dimens.xml   (320x480 and nearer resolution)
res/values-hdpi/dimens.xml   (480x800, 540x960 and nearer resolution)
res/values-xhdpi/dimens.xml  (720x1280 - Samsung S3, Micromax Canvas HD, etc) 
res/values-xxhdpi/dimens.xml (1080x1920 - Samsung S4, HTC one, etc)
res/values-large/dimens.xml  (480x800)

res/values-large-mdpi/dimens.xml (600x1024)
res/values-sw600dp/dimens.xml  (600x1024)
res/values-sw720dp/dimens.xml  (800x1280)
res/values-xlarge-xhdpi/dimens.xml (2560x1600 - Nexus 10")
res/values-large-xhdpi/dimens.xml  (1200x1920 - Nexus 7"(latest))
```

Comment: If possible, can you share me the exact values for different screens, I did it in this way for my landscape view: <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">128dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">128dp</dimen>

Comment: android:layout_width="wrap_content" instead of this
android:layout_width="@dimen/edt_width"
in different dimen files give different value for this edt_width by trying.

Comment: res/values-sw720dp/dimens.xml: "  <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">1280dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">800dp</dimen>", I gave it like this and then referred in my layout but still not working

Comment: mdpi iswrong unit and you are not giving height and width to edittext you are giving this to your parent layout. Give height and width to edittext and set its container layout as wrap content.

Comment: I'll upvote your answer as it helped me to some extent, I'll try all your suggested solutions and will mark as correct after trying it, thanks

Comment: Hey I tried your solution and it worked for all screens except for nexus10 tab's portrait layout(values-xlarge-xhdpi). Any clues for the same...??

Comment: Your welcome.. Kindly upvote it if it helps you @GeetChoubey

Comment: @PreetikaKaur for landscape mode its working perfect, but for portrait mode the layouts are not getting resized..

Comment: the top ones are for portrait mode only. I use these and they are working fine. Try to change your values of variables in files.

Comment: @PreetikaKaur  I got an issue while setting variables, the portrait layout only gets resized while setting variables in res/values-sw600dp/dimens.xml , it doesnt take the values of other dimens, any clue for that

Comment: Every device will take value from their respective folders.

Comment: @PreetikaKaur finally got it working by some tricks a.k.a "jugaad" .. :-P Thanks alot for giving your time and explaining the whole concept..!!

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Comment: Can you add the reference ??

Comment: @ArpitPatel which reference do you need ? Sizes are already mention

Comment: any blog or developer.android.com with explanation would be batter.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html official doc @ArpitPatel